# MS-Access 2007 as EXE - How to maintain and debug?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I see that you can convert an MS-Access 2007 into an .EXE file. Suppose you discovered a problem with the code, how do you fix it or debug it in the .exe format?

I am asking this because as I understand MS-Access stores the code with the data in the same file. I am assuming you can't get back to your original ACCDB file because it won't have the data collected over time in the .EXE file.

Comment: You can make an ACCDE from an ACCDB.  Is that what you meant?  An ACCDE is not an EXE.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I meant real .exe as in here for example:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aylQNvVDPsg - Creating an ACCDE is the first step only.

Comment: Notice at 1:30 the video instructs you to select "The application doesn't have a main executable file" checkbox.  That process does not convert the ACCDE to an EXE.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Kindly, look at my comment on Andre's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "convert" an Access application into an .exe file.

All the linked video does is creating a setup, which then copies the .accde into an output folder. It still needs MSACCESS.EXE (full or runtime) to run.

So the question is moot. If you find a problem in your application, you create a new .accde and deploy that to your user's computer(s).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I think I mixed this concept with this product: http://mdecompiler.com/.

Comment: That product also requires either the full or runtime version of MS Access.  The files it generates are not what most of us expect when you said EXE.

Comment: @HansUp, well, I actually did not think that MS Access would be not required. Thanks for your followup.